# Shell script - read contents of directory and display those who have greater than 20 word count

Tags: linux, shell

my script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/Directory"

if [ dir rw-w>20 ]
-print
fi
```

This script should read the contents of specified directory and print those, who has more than 20 word in them. But it doesn't work for me. Any ideas ?

Comment: What do you expect the command `[ dir rw-w ]` to do, and why are you redirecting the output of that command to a file named "20"?

Comment: I am expecting to read the directory location and count how many word it have, if it is more than 20, do the rest of commands. For file named 20, I didn't knew it is file. Sorry for my bad syntax.

Comment: Perhaps my comment was not clear.  The command `if [ dir rw-w>20 ]` does not do at all what you think it does.  It is exactly the same as executing the command `if [ dir rw-w ] > 20`, which is invoking the command `[ dir rw-w ]` with output to a newly created (or truncating an existing file) named '20'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question is: how can a shell script print the names of the files in a given directory that contain more than 20 words.  If that is the case, one simple solution would be:

```
for i in $dir/*; do 
    test -f "$i" && test $( wc -w < "$i" ) -gt 20 && echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that it worked fine, need definately to learn -gt and test syntax, never heard about it before. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what did you mean in your script, but it should be something like that.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="./"
for file in `ls $dir`; do
    count=`cat $file | wc -w`
    if [ $count -gt 20 ]; then
        cat $file
    fi
done
```